Connection does not exist right after connecting to the hub
I have a Winforms client that connects to an ASP.NET Core 7 SignalR hub. I am getting the following exception frequently:

Connection '...' does not exist.
System.IO.IOException: Connection '...' does not exist.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.DefaultHubLifetimeManager`1.InvokeConnectionAsync[T](String connectionId, String methodName, Object[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

I have increased the logging level as high as possible and nothing of interest is being logged.
Why does the problem occur if the client just connected?

If you're using load balancers or proxies between your client and server, they may occasionally drop the connection or misroute traffic, leading to lost connections.

@samwu Load balancers are not used. there is a firewall that might be also used as/with a proxy. The problem is that the client connects the first time and gets a connectionId. After further connections, the first connectionId is never replaced and is always used.

If the SignalR client isn't properly disposed of or closed before attempting a reconnection, it may retain the old connectionId. As a result, further invocations might use the old (now invalid) connectionId. ensure the client disconnects and fully disposes of the previous connection before creating a new one.
